# show hide polylines google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When page loaded all polyline autoloaded on map. 
I m need to hide it and when i click chekcbox it will show on map. how can i do it? 
Polylines  has categories.. like rayon.. i call it on checkbox  categories rayon..

P.S. sorry for my English
it my code:

```
    function getline() {
       var mpenc = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 function pinfo(poly, html) {


      google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseover",function(){ poly.setOptions({
 strokeColor:'#FFFFFF', strokeOpacity: .8});});

      google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseout",function(){ 
poly.setOptions({strokeColor:colorr});});


     google.maps.event.addListener(poly,'click', function(event) {
    mpenc.setContent(html);
    mpenc.setPosition(event.latLng);
    mpenc.open(map);
  });

}      
 alert('Loading Lines.. Please wait 10 sec.');  
downloadUrl("all.php", function(doc) {
      alert('Lines loaded..');  

      var g = google.maps; 
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);         bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
      // ========= Now process the polylines ===========
      var lines = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("line");

      // read each line
      for (var a = 0; a < lines.length; a++) {
        // get any line attributes
       var colour = lines[a].getAttribute("colour");
        var width  = parseFloat(lines[a].getAttribute("width"));
        var diameter = lines[a].getAttribute("diameter");
        var project = lines[a].getAttribute("projectid");       var type = lines[a].getAttribute("type");
        var contract = lines[a].getAttribute("contract");             var cr = lines[a].getAttribute("contractor"); if (cr) {cr1 = "  " + cr + " ";} else { cr1 = "None";}
        var comp = lines[a].getAttribute("complated");
        var id = lines[a].getAttribute("id_line");
        var html = "<b>Contractor:</b> " + cr1 + " </a> <br/> <b> Contract: </b>" + contract + " <br/><b>Line Segment:</b> " + id + " <br/><b>Project: </b>" + project +"<br/>  <b>Diameter: </b>" + diameter + " <br/> <b>Completed: </b>" + comp + "% <hr><br/><a class=\"inline-link-1\" HREF=\"javascript:void(0)\"onclick=\"window.open('cdatal.php?id="+ id +"','cdatal','height=300, width=460,scrollbars=no')\">Change completed</a> <a class=\"inline-link-1\" HREF=\"javascript:void(0)\"onclick=\"window.open('dedit.php?id="+ id +"','cdata','height=300, width=350,scrollbars=no')\">Design data</a>" ;
        // read each point on that line
        var points = lines[a].getElementsByTagName("point");
        var pts = [];
        var length = 0;
        var point = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
           pts[i] = new g.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")),
                                parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")));
           if (i > 0) {
             length += pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i]);
             if (isNaN(length)) { alert("["+i+"] length="+length+" segment="+pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i])) };
           }
           bounds.extend(pts[i]);
           point = pts[parseInt(i/2)];
        }
        // length *= 0.000621371192; // miles/meter 


  if (comp < 1) { 
 colorr = '#FA0505' }

 if (comp > 0 && comp < 25 ) { 
 colorr = '#FFA640' }

 if (comp > 24 && comp < 50) { 
 colorr = '#FFFD91' }

 if (comp > 49 && comp < 75) { 
 colorr = '#E8E400' }

 if (comp > 74 && comp < 100) { 
 colorr = '#BFFFAD' }

 if (comp == 100) { 
 colorr = '#0F8500' }
    if(type == 'dl') {en = '1'}     if(type == 'ml') {en = '3'}     if(type == 'tl') {en = '5'}

        var poly = new g.Polyline({
                          map:map,
                          path:pts,
                          strokeColor:colorr,
                          strokeWeight:en,
                          clickable: true
                          });



   pinfo(poly,html);



 }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });


}



 <li><input type="checkbox" id="value1" value="wsn/qabala.php" onclick="boxclick(this.value,'qabala','value1')" /> Qabala</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value2" value="wsn/ismailli.php"  onclick="boxclick(this.value,'ismailli','value2')" /> Ismayilli</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="value3"  value="wsn/agshu.php"   onclick="boxclick(this.value,'value3')" /> Aghsu</li> ....
```

and xml data:

```
http://nn-gis.com/map/all.php
```

Comment: The google.maps.Polyline class has a setVisible to toggle visibility

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/NCZYW/9/

```
$(function() {

    var div = $('#categories');

    var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var categories = {
        rayon: [
            {
                coordinates: [
                    [37.772323, -122.214897],
                    [21.291982, -157.821856],
                    [-18.142599, 178.431],
                    [-27.46758, 153.027892]
                ],
                color: '#FF0000'
            }
        ]
    };

    $.each(categories, function(name) {

        var paths = [];new google.maps.LatLng

        $.each(this, function(i) {

            var path = [];

            $.each(this.coordinates, function(i) {

                path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(this[0], this[1]));

            });

            paths.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: path,
                strokeColor: this.color,
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                visible: false,
                map: map
            }));

        });

        categories[name] = paths;

        div.append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + name + '"/> ' + name + '</label>');

    });

    div.on('change', 'input', function(event) {

        var checked = this.checked;

        $.each(categories[this.value], function(i) {

            this.setVisible(checked);

        });

    });

});
```

The key is to group the polylines.

Comment: yes like that. but i have 10 and more categories.. i`m need show hide this by categories not all.. is it possible ?

Comment: This way you can have several polylines under each category and hide them also by category. Fell free to add more data to customize it.

Comment: ooppss..i`d include jquery 1.9 and edited my code as your send but dont work ((

Comment: Ok, that jsfiddle won't work because of a crossdomain violation (since you are trying to load an XML from another domain. Why don't you use the jQuery ajax methods?, why don you use JSON instead of XML?, are "contract"'s the "categories"?. I think you can solve it using my example.

Comment: i`v tested another method.. i have method to show/hide markers it work successfully .. i want implement it ..not work ((..  i`d test json but dont like (( ..