# Polyline Hide not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

By this code i can show and hide markers.. This code does not work with polylines.
 When page loading all lines automaticly loaded.. Can anyone suggest how to toggle polylines in googlemap?

Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for my English

```
   var myCoordsLenght = 6;
          var gmarkers = [];


              function show(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        if (!gmarkers[i].getMap()) gmarkers[i].setMap(map); 
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
          }
        }
        // == check the checkbox ==
         document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
      }



        function hide(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
         document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
         infowindow.close();
      }

       function boxwclick(box,category) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(category);
        } else {
          hide(category);
        }

      }

    function load() {
     var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, 48.0000),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    }


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


 downloadUrl("all.php", function(doc) {
      alert('Lines loaded..');  

      var g = google.maps; 
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);         bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
      // ========= Now process the polylines ===========
      var lines = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("line");

      // read each line
      for (var a = 0; a < lines.length; a++) {
        // get any line attributes
       var colour = lines[a].getAttribute("colour");
        var width  = parseFloat(lines[a].getAttribute("width"));
        var diameter = lines[a].getAttribute("diameter");
        var project = lines[a].getAttribute("projectid");       var type = lines[a].getAttribute("type");
        var contract = lines[a].getAttribute("contract");             var cr = lines[a].getAttribute("contractor"); if (cr) {cr1 = "  " + cr + " ";} else { cr1 = "None";}
        var comp = lines[a].getAttribute("complated");
        var category = lines[a].getAttribute("rayon");
        var id = lines[a].getAttribute("id_line");
        var html = "<b>Contractor:</b> " + cr1 + " </a> <br/> <b> Contract: </b>" + contract + " <br/><b>Line Segment:</b> " + id + " <br/><b>Project: </b>" + project +"<br/>  <b>Diameter: </b>" + diameter + " <br/> <b>Completed: </b>" + comp + "% <hr><br/><a class=\"inline-link-1\" HREF=\"javascript:void(0)\"onclick=\"window.open('cdatal.php?id="+ id +"','cdatal','height=300, width=460,scrollbars=no')\">Change completed</a> <a class=\"inline-link-1\" HREF=\"javascript:void(0)\"onclick=\"window.open('dedit.php?id="+ id +"','cdata','height=300, width=350,scrollbars=no')\">Design data</a>" ;
        // read each point on that line
        var points = lines[a].getElementsByTagName("point");
        var pts = [];
        var length = 0;
        var point = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
           pts[i] = new g.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")),
                                parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")));
           if (i > 0) {
             length += pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i]);
             if (isNaN(length)) { alert("["+i+"] length="+length+" segment="+pts[i-1].distanceFrom(pts[i])) };
           }
           bounds.extend(pts[i]);
           point = pts[parseInt(i/2)];
        }
        // length *= 0.000621371192; // miles/meter 


  if (comp < 1) { 
 colorr = '#FA0505' }

 if (comp > 0 && comp < 25 ) { 
 colorr = '#FFA640' }

 if (comp > 24 && comp < 50) { 
 colorr = '#FFFD91' }

 if (comp > 49 && comp < 75) { 
 colorr = '#E8E400' }

 if (comp > 74 && comp < 100) { 
 colorr = '#BFFFAD' }

 if (comp == 100) { 
 colorr = '#0F8500' }
    if(type == 'dl') {en = '1'}     if(type == 'ml') {en = '3'}     if(type == 'tl') {en = '5'}

        var marker = new g.Polyline({
                          map:map,
                          path:pts,
                          strokeColor:colorr,
                          strokeWeight:en,
                          clickable: true
                          });




        marker.mycategory = category;                                 
        marker.myname = name;
        gmarkers.push(marker);

        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

 }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });

 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, category) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

       infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      });
    }
/***************************************************************/
 }
```

HTML:

```
<li> <input type="checkbox" id="Siyazanbox" onclick="boxwclick(this,'Siyazan')" /> <label>Siyazan</label></li>
```

XML:

```
<marker><line id_line="1" colour="null" width="2" diameter="110" contract="WWS2" contractor="SADE Compagnie Generale de Travaux D'Hydraulique" projectid="NWSSP-2" complated="0" rayon="Siyazan" type="dl" coordinats="49.1221079493,41.0833787143;49.1227564511,41.0838059721;49.1230700892,41.0839889587;49.1241003797,41.0845428473"><point lng="41.0833787143" lat="49.1221079493"/><point lng="41.0838059721" lat="49.1227564511"/><point lng="41.0839889587" lat="49.1230700892"/><point lng="41.0845428473" lat="49.1241003797"/></line><line id_line="2" colour="null" width="2" diameter="110" contract="WWS2" contractor="SADE Compagnie Generale de Travaux D'Hydraulique" projectid="NWSSP-2" complated="0" rayon="Siyazan" type="dl" coordinats="49.1154421711,41.0761833833;49.1165550376,41.0749755563;49.1175163898,41.0740599835;49.1180954926,41.0734165180;49.1185257918,41.0727815949;49.1186139922,41.0726310877;49.1182901054,41.0724703018"><point lng="41.0761833833" lat="49.1154421711"/><point lng="41.0749755563" lat="49.1165550376"/><point lng="41.0740599835" lat="49.1175163898"/><point lng="41.0734165180" lat="49.1180954926"/><point lng="41.0727815949" lat="49.1185257918"/><point lng="41.0726310877" lat="49.1186139922"/><point lng="41.0724703018" lat="49.1182901054"/></line><line id_line="3" colour="null" width="2" diameter="110" contract="WWS2" contractor="SADE Compagnie Generale de Travaux D'Hydraulique" projectid="NWSSP-2" complated="0" rayon="Siyazan" type="dl" coordinats="49.1094929100,41.0733611765;49.1099543208,41.0733355826;49.1104145028,41.0733449452"><point lng="41.0733611765" lat="49.1094929100"/><point lng="41.0733355826" lat="49.1099543208"/><point lng="41.0733449452" lat="49.1104145028"/></line><line id_line="4" colour="null" width="2" diameter="110" contract="WWS2" contractor="SADE Compagnie Generale de Travaux D'Hydraulique" projectid="NWSSP-2" complated="0" rayon="Siyazan" type="dl" coordinats="49.1102213081,41.0792663250;49.1096951515,41.0788617355;49.1095352693,41.0787634195;49.1093125815,41.0786383847"><point lng="41.0792663250" lat="49.1102213081"/><point lng="41.0788617355" lat="49.1096951515"/><point lng="41.0787634195" lat="49.1095352693"/><point lng="41.0786383847" lat="49.1093125815"/></line><line id_line="5" colour="null" width="2" diameter="110" contract="WWS2" contractor="SADE Compagnie Generale de Travaux D'Hydraulique" projectid="NWSSP-2" complated="0" rayon="Siyazan" type="dl" coordinats="49.1087112084,41.0777986205;49.1090009844,41.0779000181;49.1091705193,41.0779693910;49.1097055392,41.0782304164"><point lng="41.0777986205" lat="49.1087112084"/><point lng="41.0779000181" lat="49.1090009844"/><point lng="41.0779693910" lat="49.1091705193"/><point lng="41.0782304164" lat="49.1097055392"/></line><line id_line="6" colour="null" width="2" diameter="110" contract="WWS2" contractor="SADE Compagnie Generale de Travaux D'Hydraulique" projectid="NWSSP-2" complated="0" rayon="Siyazan" type="dl" coordinats="49.1110047809,41.0815780616;49.1110894030,41.0814954941;49.1111775916,41.0814095421;49.1114574103,41.0811056406;49.1117100334,41.0808386785;49.1119646593,41.0806189159;49.1121959306,41.0803810984;49.1123847807,41.0802126892;49.1125497290,41.0800566494;49.1126203282,41.0800033545"><point lng="41.0815780616" lat="49.1110047809"/><point lng="41.0814954941" lat="49.1110894030"/><point lng="41.0814095421" lat="49.1111775916"/><point lng="41.0811056406" lat="49.1114574103"/><point lng="41.0808386785" lat="49.1117100334"/><point lng="41.0806189159" lat="49.1119646593"/><point lng="41.0803810984" lat="49.1121959306"/><point lng="41.0802126892" lat="49.1123847807"/><point lng="41.0800566494" lat="49.1125497290"/><point lng="41.0800033545" lat="49.1126203282"/></line>
```

Comment: please provide the entire code, including html

Comment: Please, **stop duplicating your own question** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373467/show-hide-polylines-google-maps (The google.maps.Polyline class has a setVisible to toggle visibility)

Comment: no.. its not duplicate! i create other method want use this method.. question same but method isnt!

Answer (score 0):

To toggle a polyline:

```
yourPolyLine.setMap(yourMap);
yourPolyLine.setMap(null);
```